# C# Using array.Where in Arraylist

Tags: c#, arrays

I have sets of codes in C# with array and I need to **split** the array into smaller size array.
I have no errors when declaring the array with :

```
List<int> array = new List<int>();
```

However, the code execution prompts out error at the **array.Where** when I declare as :

```
var array = new ArrayList();
```

Is there any way I can use **array.Where** in array list? Below is my code :

```
List<int> array = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i <=20; i++){
  if (unitIsPresent) 
  {
    array.add(1);
  } 
  else
  {
    array.add(0)
  }
}

devidedArray = array.Where((e, i) => i >= 5 && i < 10).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` in the first place?

Comment: Things like `Where` are LINQ extension methods on anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>` (e.g. `List<T>`, where `T` is `int` in your example). `ArrayList` isn't generic so it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only `IEnumerable`. These methods are therefore not available. When even the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0#remarks) recommend against using `ArrayList` for new development, I have to echo Sweeper's question of "why are you using `ArrayList` in the first place?"

Comment: "Is there any way I can use array.Where in array list?" short answer: No

Comment: @MongZhu well... not *quite* no; one could define their own extension method (for example `public static IEnumerable<object> Where(this ArrayList list, Func<object, bool> predicate) => list.Cast<object>().Where(predicate);`), but it *wouldn't be a good idea*; totally agree with the sentiment that "don't use `ArrayList`" is the place to start with this one!

Comment: @MarcGravell thanx for the cherry picking detail :)

Comment: @MongZhu https://i.imgur.com/PpV0evc.png

Comment: To spell it out: __`ArrayList` is deprecated__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use an `ArrayList` (really? why?), you can use `OfType<int>()` to change the `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<int>`.

```
var devidedArray = array.OfType<int>().Where((e, i) => i >= 5 && i < 10).ToArray();
```

Alternatively you could use `Cast<int>()`:

```
var devidedArray = array.Cast<int>().Where((e, i) => i >= 5 && i < 10).ToArray();
```

The difference between the two is that `OfType()` will silently ignore objects that cannot be cast to `int` while `Cast()` will fail with an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 6):

Array List is a non generic collection type so it's good to store items in array where you don't consider the items types. So for this reason you can't use Linq methods that are used for generics collections like Where.
My recommendation is use a List and convert it to Array with the Linq method provided.this way is very fast.

Answer (score 4):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0

look microsoft doc.

We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List class. ...

just use `List<T>` to replace `ArrayList`.